# Unable to activate wordnet - require 'wordnet' fails

Tags: ruby, rubygems, wordnet

I am writing a Ruby script, and I would like to use wordNet to stem String. I want to give it a string that may contain words of the same form and get back the string but after stemming it. I came across [Ruby-WordNet](http://deveiate.org/code/wordnet/index.html) and installed [wordnet gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/wordnet) and [wordnet-defaultdb gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/wordnet-defaultdb). I also installed [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) since it is required.

However, I am not sure how to deal with it. When I typed in the script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sequel'
require 'wordnet'
```

I get the following error:

```
/Users/arwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-  2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2112:in  `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate wordnet-1.0.0, because sequel-4.24.0  conflicts with sequel (~> 3.38) (Gem::ConflictError)
from /Users/arwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby- 2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1280:in `activate'
from /Users/arwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:198:in `rescue in try_activate'
from /Users/arwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:195:in `try_activate'
from /Users/arwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/arwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
from ./test.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

If I removed

```
require 'sequel'
```

I get the following error:

```
/Users/arwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require': cannot load such file -- sequel (LoadError)
from /Users/arwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/arwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
from /Users/arwa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/wordnet-1.0.0/lib/wordnet.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/arwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
from /Users/arwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/arwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
from ./test.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

I am not sure what is the problem and how to deal with it.

Does any one have any idea on how it works?

Also, if someone can direct me to a place where I can find example on how to code it and to deal with it.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems you have a gem conflict. ty removing `require 'sequel'`

Comment: I edited the answer to show you what I get if i remove it

Comment: Please do NOT use images to show us code or errors. Copy/paste the error and format correctly. An image forces us to type in the important information when searching, and keeps search engines from finding your question when someone is looking for the answer to the same question. Image links also rot and break, making your question useless to everyone.

Comment: The answer of your problem was already in the error message:Unable to activate wordnet-1.0.0, because sequel-4.24.0 conflicts with sequel (~> 3.38) (Gem::ConflictError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says you have a version conflict.

See what `gem list sequel --all` says. Odds are good you loaded only the latest version of Sequel by using `gem install sequel` without specifying the version, or that you have two versions, the one specified by WordNet and the latest

Try removing/uninstalling all Sequel versions installed and reinstall only the specific version:

```
gem install sequel -v3.38
```

You can also try modifying the gem requirements for WordNet to not require a specific version of Sequel. Sequel is extremely stable so that should be a safe move.

Answer (score 0):

You have conflicting gem versions installed:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'sequel', '3.48'
require 'sequel'
require 'wordnet'
```

Will solve your issue.

You can help yourself with a `Gemfile`. Run `bundle init` to create one. Run `gem install bundler` if you have no bundler.

Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'sequel'
gem 'wordnet'
```

Run `bundle` after you saved your Gemfile. Check `Gemfile.lock` for the solution.